# Empty div before append

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, append

I'm trying to append some html code with a loop into an html tag.
But every time that my loop refresh itself the code is appended a second time.
I tried to use `$(#nodes).empty();` before the loop but with this method i get a blank screen.

This is the code snippet

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
 var interval = 10000;
 var refresh = function() {
 $.getJSON("https://tankionline.com/s/status.js",function(json){
   console.log("updated");
   var nodes = Object.keys(json.nodes).length;
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes; i++) {
      var num = i + 1;
      var main = 'main.c' + num;
      $("#nodes").append(`
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">${num}</th>
          <td> ${json.nodes[main].online} </td>
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
        </tr>
        `)
     }
 });
 setTimeout(function() {
   refresh();
     },
   interval);
     }
   refresh();
```

});

Comment: Using `$("#nodes").empty();` before the loop sounds like the right thing. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: The `.empty()` method, as in the answer below, is fine. But you could aslo simply use `.html()` instead of `.append()`...

Comment: You are right, using `$("#nodes").empty();` is the right thing but I forgot to put the nodes between "", so everything after that was not working, jsfiddle showed me the error that i lost one hour on D:

Comment: FYI: `setTimeout(function() {  refresh();  }, ...` should just be `setTimeout(refresh, ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it with the mentioned `$("#nodes").empty();` before the loop and it is just working fine:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/moEPrP?editors=1010

```
var refresh = function() {
   $("#nodes").empty();
   $.getJSON("https://tankionline.com/s/status.js",function(json){
      console.log("updated");
   ....
```